# How to check if a table/class exists in Realm database in android?

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

In a scenario, I need to check that if my expected table/class exists in the realm database or not. Because if I do some queries like this using `DynamicRealm` -

```
  DynamicRealm  dynamicRealm = DynamicRealm.getInstance(myRealmConfig);

  dynamicRealm.where("myExpectedClass").findAll();
```

Then I'm getting an exception like that -

```
Class does not exist in the Realm and cannot be queried: myExpectedClass
```

So to prevent this exception, I need to make it sure first that it is existing in database or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just debugged and found some methods to check this case and made an exception free reusable method -

```
         /**
         * @param dynamicRealm      The source dynamic realm created using the same realm configuration.
         * @param clazzNameExpected The CASE-SENSITIVE name of the expected class we want to check whatever it is existing in
         *                          realm database or not.
         * @return
         */

       public static boolean isClassExistInRealmDB(DynamicRealm dynamicRealm,String clazzNameExpected) {
            return (dynamicRealm != null && dynamicRealm.getSchema() != null) &&
                    dynamicRealm.getSchema().contains(clazzNameExpected);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
dynamicRealm.getSchema().contains("myExpectedClass")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is the real workable answer.